# Installing error with six dependency

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, six

`Running setup.py install for anyjson ... done
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-29Cml5-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'`

Snippet of error stacktrace. 
While running requirements.txt on python.
Is it due to six.

Ignoring it does NOT help.

`sudo -H pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed six
Double requirement given: six==1.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 107)) (already in six, name='six')`

This post does not help - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

Comment: i take it you're not using virtualenv here? that would be the cleanest workaround.

Comment: @ingernet Some of Apple's `Extras` stuff will actually prevent `pip install` from working within a venv. But it's definitely worth trying that first, unless the OP can't use venvs for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the `Extras` problem I'm going to describe does not affect venvs. Sometimes it does, but if using `virtualenv` is at all an option, you should try that before doing anything else.

So, let's assume you either can't do that, or you tried it and this is one of the cases where it doesn't actually help.

---

First, let me say that all of the following is terrible, terrible advice for any purpose *except* installing new versions of packages that Apple pre-installed in `Extras` with Apple's Python 2.7 in OS X 10.7-10.13. Anyone reading this who does not have exactly that problem, stop reading now.

Apple's system version of Python 2.7 comes with a nifty set of third-party packages preinstalled in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/
```

Rather than try to keep these packages up to date, they designed things so that you can easily shadow them with a newer version in your `site-packages` directory. Which wasn't a terrible idea.

Unfortunately, they stopped doing any serious maintenance on this a few versions of OS X back, but didn't stop shipping it. In particular, they never updated it to work with `setuptools` and `pip`, and if you install `pip` properly (using the `get-pip.py` script instead of `easy_install`), shadowing installs will basically never work.

---

If your pre-installed `easy_install` is still working, it *should* still work to install shadowing packages. Do not use it for anything else, but for this specific purpose, it's the right tool. But it doesn't work for every package on every OS X version, so it's a bit of trial and error. You may want to back up `Extras` and `site-packages` first just in case.

---

The way to test it (assuming `easy_install` succeeds, of course—if it fails with a slew of errors, it obviously didn't work… and it's time to restore your backups) is to start Python, `import six`, and look at `six.__version__` or `six.__file__`. If it's the new version in `site-packages`, you win.

---

If that doesn't work, there's a hacky workaround that may solve your problem: Temporarily move the file `Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info` somewhere else, then see if `pip install six` successfully installs into your normal `site-packages`. If so, restore the egg-info file, and test the shadowing again.

---

If that *still* didn't work… well, you *can* install manually, but I think at this point, the pain of having two Python 2.7 installations in parallel is less than the pain of managing the one you have, so I'd consider installing another one (python.org, Anaconda, or Homebrew) and being careful to never touch the Apple one again (`virtualenv` can help with this).